# Which is better/safer to use: HandleRef or IntPtr (newer source code from Microsoft no longer uses HandleRef)

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, native, intptr

For example, in the old .NET Framework 2.0 Source Code (Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2005 - Whidbey), the *GetClientRect* function was defined using **HandleRef**:

```
    [DllImport(ExternDll.User32, ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool GetClientRect(HandleRef hWnd, [In, Out] ref NativeMethods.RECT rect);
```

In the new Windows API Code Pack (from Microsoft, 2009/2010) the same function is defined using **IntPtr**:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref CoreNativeMethods.RECT rect);
```

Actually **HandleRef** is not used in any of the Windows API Code Pack source files, while it was heavily used in the native methods signatures in the old .NET Framework source files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntPtr, SafeHandle and HandleRef - Explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526661/intptr-safehandle-and-handleref-explained)

Comment: When possible use a SafeHandle so you get critical finalization and are don't need GC.KeepAlive.

Comment: @Cody Gray both that question, and the answers at the time I write this, do not really address the question actually being asked here - why has the MS source for the *same* functions changed from one to the other?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, SafeHandle serves a different purpose to HandleRef and GC.KeepAlive. SafeHandle is a way to ensure a native handle is (eventually) released without terminating the process, even when really bad stuff happens. HandleRef and GC.KeepAlive are used to tell the GC that the object is still in use outside it's vision.

Comment: @BrianReichle When using a SafeHandle in native interop, the marshaller will keep the handle alive until the native function returns, removing the need for GC.KeepAlive in many situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bit fishy.  HandleRef is not needed when handle values are stored in a SafeHandle derived object.  Which the code pack declares, ZeroInvalidHandle, with several derived ones from it like SafeWindowHandle.

However, it doesn't actually *use* any of these SafeHandle classes anywhere.  Not so sure if it really has to, a lot of the Vista and Win7 extensions are actually COM interfaces.  Not the traditional handle based C API.  They are kept alive through reference counts and are thus not subject to this kind of garbage collector mishap.

Personally I just never worry about this.  Getting a class object collected *while* the API call is executing is a bug.  It can happen just as easily a microsecond *after* the API call completed.  Still a bug, just not one that makes the API call fail.  Not so sure I'd actually want it to not fail, I'd much prefer an exception when I got a bug in my code.  Microsoft needs to protect itself from this, they don't want to get the blame for the exception.  I do.

Answer (score 5):

**My guess is that the newer code samples use `IntPtr` merely because it's simpler to understand.**

A quick glance through Reflector at the function signatures in the various `NativeMethods` classes found in the .NET Framework shows that the actual usage is pretty well split between the two.

I assume this is based on whether or not there is a need to prevent the object from being garbage collected prematurely (which is the [primary advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526661/intptr-safehandle-and-handleref-explained) to using `HandleRef`). Also keep in mind that using `HandleRef` is unnecessary unless the handle that you're passing is to a *managed* object. Unmanaged objects will not get garbage collected.

Comment: @Hans: That's true. The distinction I was trying to make involves objects like forms that, while not actually fully managed objects, are eligible for garbage collection and whose handles can potentially be invalidated if they are not referenced again in your code. If you've passed this handle to a p/invoke function in the meantime, this could create a problem. For unmanaged objects that you've created yourself, this isn't a problem because they will not be garbage collected.

Comment: I know, your answer covers that.  Just the last sentence is nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

**IntPtr** is just structure that wraps pointer. As for **HandleRef** MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref.aspx) "Wrapping a handle with HandleRef guarantees that the managed object is not garbage collected until the platform invoke call completes." There is a chance that GC can finalize handle during P/Invoke if you don't do anything with it after P/Invoke call. So HandleRef looks more safe.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "wraps pointer." The important thing about `IntPtr` is that it's size is platform-specific (32-bits in 32-bit environments, 64-bits in 64-bit environments). It's commonly used to hold pointers or handles, but it doesn't *wrap* them.

Comment: IntPtr is a structure, but actual pointer is inside and it depends on environment that's why I said it wraps. Maybe it's incorrect and "holds pointer" sounds better. I agree