# .NET Core equivalent for HandleRef?

Tags: interop, asp.net-core, intptr

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't see `HandleRef` in .NET Core.

So, what is the safe/recommended way for managing references to `IntPtr` in .NET Core?

Comment: Looks like HandleRef (and SafeHandle) will be available with .NET Core 2.0 [#12162](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12162).

Comment: I think a bit more details about your intent would help to provide a good answer. (Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348119/safehandle-and-handleref or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526661/intptr-safehandle-and-handleref-explained already provide the information you need.)