Google.OrTools.Sat CPSolver.Solve causes AccessViolationException
I'm following along with this video it's in python I'm converting to dotnet as I go.
As soon as I ran the app it crashed. I removed everything down to this reproduction.
I can only assume that there is some setup I've missed. Any hints
program.cs
using Google.OrTools.Sat; // 9.10.4067

var model = new CpModel();
var solver = new CpSolver();
solver.Solve(model);

// an attempt to prevent the crash as per other SO post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296373/accessviolationexception-when-accessing-variable-solution-value
GC.KeepAlive(model);
GC.KeepAlive(solver);

output
%USER_PROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Rider\plugins\dpa\DotFiles\JetBrains.DPA.Runner.exe --handle=14376 --backend-pid=6556 --etw-collect-flags=67108622 --detach-event-name=dpa.detach.14376 %LOCAL_PATH%/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp1.exe
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Repeat 2 times:
--------------------------------
   at Google.OrTools.Sat.operations_research_satPINVOKE.SolveWrapper_Solve(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Byte[])
--------------------------------
   at Google.OrTools.Sat.SolveWrapper.Solve(Google.OrTools.Sat.CpModelProto)
   at Google.OrTools.Sat.CpSolver.Solve(Google.OrTools.Sat.CpModel, Google.OrTools.Sat.SolutionCallback)
   at Program.<Main>$(System.String[])

Process finished with exit code 0xC0000005.

proj file
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.OrTools" Version="9.10.4067" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>


As per answer below I installed the latest version or MS VC++ Redistributable see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#latest-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-version

There is a nasty bug in visual studio 2022 between compiler versions (17.8 vs 17.9). Please make sure to follow the solution in https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/4225. and report if it does not solve your problem.
