Segmentation fault while using CP-SAT solver of ortools in vscode
I am trying to run google ortools in vscode. In specific I am trying to run CP-SAT solver. While running the code, it is giving me segmentation fault. I don't know what to do. Also can we use ortools in vscode for package development? If yes, how? Otherwise, are there any other good IDEs to use? I am using python.
This is my code:
"""Simple solve."""
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


def simple_sat_program():
    """Minimal CP-SAT example to showcase calling the solver."""
    # Creates the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Creates the variables.
    num_vals = 3
    x = model.new_int_var(0, num_vals - 1, "x")
    y = model.new_int_var(0, num_vals - 1, "y")
    z = model.new_int_var(0, num_vals - 1, "z")

    # Creates the constraints.
    model.add(x != y)

    # Creates a solver and solves the model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    status = solver.solve(model)

    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        print(f"x = {solver.value(x)}")
        print(f"y = {solver.value(y)}")
        print(f"z = {solver.value(z)}")
    else:
        print("No solution found.")


simple_sat_program()

This is the error I am getting:
python demo.py
Segmentation fault


I am using vscode all the time. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78489444/google-ortools-sat-cpsolver-solve-causes-accessviolationexception ?
